# Docker, port 3000 is unavailable

Tags: docker, port, grafana, http-status-code-500

I was doing some learning with Graphite and Grafana using some containers to run some tests, it was working normally but had a power outage in the middle of it, now when I try to build the containers, the one that uses port 3000 throws an error code (HTTP code 500) and the next message

> Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3000: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

netstat says the port is not in use and just can't find it regardless of anything
and killing the port with the command

> npx kill-port 3000

Doesn't do anything, any ideas why this might be happening? I also can't use another port because the configuration inside the container explicitly uses port 3000.

[edit]

Here's is the image of the terminal when I try to build the container
[PowerShell Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIm7l.png)

Comment: Have you tried use the administration mode to open Power Shell ?

Comment: Yes, and unfortunately, it made no difference

Answer (score 1):

Well, after letting my PC turned off for the night and trying again, the port seems to be open now... I really don't know what happened, why is it working now nor how...
My only guess its that maybe my router restarted or something, in any case, it's solved

Comment: This is unfortunately the answer to most unresolvable port issues - the ol' reboot. There are a number of things which can cause a system to think that a PORT is still tied up - and in the event of a catastrophic failure (eg. losing power), your best bet is to reboot... sadly. Other things to try before rebooting is to `pkill node` (and any other process which was attached to the port).

Comment: Weird thing is, I did reboot beforehand, completely shut down my PC and then turn on and nothing, now I wake up, try again, and works as if nothing happened, oh well

Comment: Oh yeah, in that case you just need to open your task manager, close all processes (even system processes), open your terminal and run `rm -rf /`, and then pick up your computer and throw it out your balcony window... hopefully into a pool below. Make sure nobody is in the pool first. _(note: please do not do any of the above)_.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the port the container exposes is not a concern. When binding ports you attach the container's exposed port to any available port on the host.

So, you can do something like `-p 80:3000` and access your container directly at `localhost`.

Unfortunately, why the port is unavailable is a mystery to me. Perhaps you could share your `docker run` command?

Comment: yeah, I know I can expose the container to any port, but Grafana doesn't like that, and won't open the dashboard otherwise, ill add the image of the terminal output in the main question.